# Passing a table name as a parameter to multiple SELECTs

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have an SQL query that summarises columns of a table `table_name` (BigQuery Console) along the lines:

SELECT

```
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `table_name` WHERE A_col = 'Hello') /
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `table_name`) * 100 AS A_something,

(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `table_name` WHERE B_col IS NULL) /
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `table_name`) * 100 AS B_something
```

How is it possible to have only a single place to specify `table_name` in the SQL query, so inside all the per-column SELECT's it's a parameter? For example:

```
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM m WHERE B_col IS NULL) /
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM m) * 100 AS B_something
```

Comment: BigQuery won't allow you to parameterize table names, column names, etc.  [documenation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/parameterized-queries).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would just use conditional aggregation:

```
select avg(case when a_col = 'Hello' then 100.0 else 0 end) as a_something,
       avg(case when b_col is null then 100.0 else 0 end) as b_something
from m
```

If you want to use this expression multiple times, use a CTE:

```
with params as (
      select avg(case when a_col = 'Hello' then 100.0 else 0 end) as a_something,
             avg(case when b_col is null then 100.0 else 0 end) as b_something
      from m
     )
select . . .
from params cross join
     . . .
```

Comment: Other answers are great as well, but this is a very slick answer! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can use a CTE (Common Table Expression). You don't mention what database you are using. As an example, the following query will work in PostgreSQL:

```
with
m as (
  select * from table_name
)
select
  (select count(*) from m where a_col = 'Hello') / 
  (select count(*) from m) * 100 as a_something,
  (select count(*) from m where b_col = 'Hello') / 
  (select count(*) from m) * 100 as b_something
```

Answer (score 1):

For BigQuery Standard SQL

```
SELECT 
  100 * COUNTIF(A_col = 'Hello') /  COUNT(*) AS A_something,
  100 * COUNTIF(B_col IS NULL) / COUNT(*)  AS B_something
FROM `table_name`
```